# Integrating Dropzone Into An AngularJS Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js

I'm trying to integrate a Dropzone into an AngularJS page, but I'm not having much luck. I was able to get the Dropzone code to work in a page by itself, but when I put it into the file with the AngularJS code, it doesn't work. I need the Dropzone to work with other form elements (i.e. text fields, text areas, combo-boxes, etc.), not just by itself. Here is my code:

```
<div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
<div ng-if="CustomerID > 0">
<form name="crForm" action="php/process_cr_form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-submit="login()" role="form">
<!-- <form name="form" ng-submit="login()" role="form"> -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="summary">Summary/Title of the Request</label>
        <input type="text" name="summary" id="summary" class="form-control" ng-model="summary" required />
        <span ng-show="form.summary.$dirty && form.summary.$error.required" class="help-block">Summary/Title is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description of the Request</label>
        <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control" ng-model="description" required></textarea>
        <span ng-show="form.description.$dirty && form.description.$error.required" class="help-block">Description is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button id="submit" type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div ng-if="!CustomerID > 0">
<a href="#/login">Logout</a>
</div>
<script>
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    paramName: "files", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    parallelUploads: 25,
    maxFiles: 25,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*,.xls,.xlsx,.doc,.docx,.pdf',
    init: function() {
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
        myDropzone = this; // closure

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", function() {
            myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
        });

        this.on("addedfile", function() {
        });

        this.on("complete", function(file) {
            myDropzone.removeFile(file);
        });
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` doesn't tell us much.  What happened?

Comment: Good question! I'm sorry that I didn't give more details. Nothing really happens. The div (i.e. the dropzone) shows up, and that's it. The cursor doesn't turn to a finger when you mouse over it. If you click into the dropzone, it doesn't pop up a file picker. If you drag an image file onto the dropzone, it just pops up in the browser window like it would for any page that you dragged an image onto. No errors show up in the console. It's really weird. I hate to say it, but it just doesn't work. I really wish that I could give you more clues! Thanks so much for responding!

Comment: I've been doing extensive research, and I think that the problem may have something to do with the fact that I'm using ng-view. I have a main index page that has an ng-view div. The code that you see above is placed into that div when the page is called. I hope this rings a bell with someone.

Comment: I found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088603/dropzone-becomes-inactive-when-used-in-angularjs-ng-view, but I'm really new to AngularJS, and I don't understand how to set up the directive. I'm hoping that someone can clarify it for me. The problem description matches my issue pretty much exactly.